# Bootstrap Tabs how to tell which tab is the active one in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tabs

There's a similar thread about this, but it's in AngularJS. How do I tell which tab in the Bootstrap 3 Tabs as the "active" one in **jQuery** only?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the active tab by doing:

```
$('.nav').find('li.active')
```

You can easily replace the .nav with the selector that will identify the UL tag surrounding your tabs.